# Scatter plots in ggplot2 with non linear trend line

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatterplot

I'm trying to create a scatter plot using ggplot.  The x value goes roughly from 0-20, and the y value goes from 0-~50. The data is raw so it's not nice and neat and I need to plot a curved line through the majority of the data. 
The code I'm trying to use is

```
ggplot(temperature, Number.of.Fish,aes(x=Temperature,y=Number.of.Fish))+geom_smooth
```

But I keep getting an error message: error in inherits (mapping, "uneval"), could not find function "Number.of.Fish"

Comment: This sort of question is best asked on the [ggplot2 mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ggplot2)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is only about software. If a *reproducible* example were provided it likely would be welcome on SO.

Answer (score 3):

The correct code should be

```
ggplot(temperature,aes(x=Temperature,y=Number.of.Fish)) + geom_smooth()
```

You made two mistakes. First, the parenthesis `()` after `geom_smooth` and secondly, extra variable `Number.of.Fish` after the data frame `temperature`. Also, please always include a reproducible example when asking a question. This is what I did for you.

```
x <- 0:20
temperature <- data.frame(Temperature=x,Number.of.Fish = rnorm(mean=x, sd=2, n=21))
ggplot(temperature,aes(x=Temperature,y=Number.of.Fish)) + geom_smooth()
```

Comment: Thanks that really helps, but does it matter if x and y axis are unequal (number of fish 1:50, temperature 0:20.67)?

Comment: lengths of x and y have to be same. If for one x you have multiple y, you may replicate same value of x. for example `x <- c(1,1,1)` and `y <- c(20,32,45)` so both vectors have same lengths.